# I couldn't add items in radiobutton list with Item.Add(item)

Tags: asp.net

I tried to add radio button list items dynamically with code and i got this error:

> System.Web.UI.WebControls.RadioButton' does not contain a definition
>   for 'Items'and no extension method 'Items' accepting a first argument
>   of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.RadioButton' could be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

My code is:

```
RadioButton:  ID="lstBorder"
```

In pageLoad Event:

```
createed ListItem objects item.
lstBorder.Items.Add(item;
```

I didn't even get the part if Items is not a property in radio button list? How could i fix it?

Comment: Please show your real code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try in this way,

```
lstBorder.DataSource = item;
lstBorder.DataBind();
```

As Per your code, you need to add "item"(ListItem) to your radiobuttonlist

```
lstBorder.Items.Add(item);
```

Comment: ListItem item = new ListItem();
item.Text = BorderStyle.None.ToString();
 item.Value = ((int)BorderStyle.None).ToString();
lstBorder.Items.Add(); //This is my code and its not working. i am learning by reading a book.

Comment: I am getting this error - System.Web.UI - WebControls. -RadioButton' does not contain a definition for 'Items'

Comment: @Gaurav What's that BorderStyle.None.TosString(); ?

Comment: My bad. its supposed to be RadioButtonList and i have been doing on radionButton control. thank you gkrishy for replying on my question and trying to help me out. thank you.

Comment: actually i did a mistake using RadioButton, its supposed to be a RadioButtonList to add items on ListItem object. Thank you guys, trying to help me out. I would be back if any problem came in future.